# Ссылки меню навигации вылезают за пределы ограничения контента справа

Tags: html, css

Ниже код, задача: сделать так чтобы меню навигации не вылезало за пределы ограничения контента.
Все перепробовал, пока не нашел как. Подскажите если знаете, пожалуйста.

```css
*,*:before,*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  
}
.container {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 50;
}
.header:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: 2;
}
.header_body {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  align-items: center;
}
.header_logo {
  flex: 0 0 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.header_logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.header_burger {
  display: none;
}
.header_menu {
 
}
.header_list {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.header_list li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
.header_link {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
  body.lock {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .header_body {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .header_logo {
    flex: 0 0 40px;
  }
  .header_burger {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
  .header_burger span {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    top: 9px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  }
  .header_burger:before,
  .header_burger:after {
    content:'';
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    left:0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  }
  .header_burger:before {
    top: 0;
  }
  .header_burger:after {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .header_burger.active:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 9px;
  }
  .header_burger.active:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    bottom: 9px;
  }
  .header_burger.active span {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  .header_menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 70px 10px 20px 10px;
  }
  .header_menu.active {
    top: 0;
  }
  .header_list {
    display: block;
  }
  .header_list li {
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  }
  .header_link {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
.content {
  padding: 100px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.content_text {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.content_text p {
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
  .content {
    padding: 70px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Adaptive content&menu Hamburger</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="header_body">
          <a href="#" class="header_logo">
             <img src="https://github.com/EvgeniyR1987/Adaptive-content-menu-Hamburger/blob/main/logo.jpg?raw=true" alt="logo">
            </a>
          <div class="header_burger">                   
               <span></span>
           </div>
          <nav class="header_menu">
            <ul class="header_list">
              <li>
                 <a href="#" class="header_link">Главная
                </a>
                </li>
              <li>
                 <a href="#" class="header_link">О компании
                </a>
                </li>
              <li>
                 <a href="#" class="header_link">Контакты
                </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
      </nav>
        </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="content_text">
 <p>Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff </p>
        <p>Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff </p>
        <p>Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff </p>
        <p>Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff </p>
        <p>Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff </p>
        <p>Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff Fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff   ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff </p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `max-width: 1440px;` - это ограничение? Если да - меню и не вылазит за него... это у вас так контент переносится. Если правильно помню, добавьте стиль `word-break: break-all;` для content_text и будет текст упираться в "ограничение"

Comment: Таких длинных слов не бывает за исключением автомотовелозапчасти

Comment: InDevX, спасибо-помогло. Да, ограничение 1440px планировалось и для шапки и для контента.

Answer (score 0):

Вам бы табуляцию поправить в коде не помешало 
upd. Содержимое `header` не вылазит из контейнера.
[image: Ваша шапка не вылазит за границы контейнера]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос